# How to validate form using another php file?

Tags: php, html

I am new to web designing. Now, I have created a form, and if the user input doesn't meet the requirements I display error message, and if it does I do some mysql commands to enter the info to the database. Now one way to do this is to code the php file into the html and use this command,`<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> like described [here][1]`

But I don't want to put the script in the same file. How do I do that in another php file such that if user input is invalid, it will return to the homepage with the error message updated?

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="register.css">
</head>
<h1>Register as A new user</h1>

    <div id="signup">
        <form id="registration_form" action="registration.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="passwd"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Repeat Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="repasswd"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>            
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="sign up"/>

        </form>
    </div>
```

What should be in the registration.php? Like the link, I do everything, I set a flag to the error, Now if the flag is true I return the user to the homepage with the error messages, and if false, I show a message saying registration successful. How do I do the part,"return to homepage with the appended error message"?

Comment: Can you post your code here ?

Comment: it's pretty standard to just post to action="do_stuff_action.php"... a different page..like poster said above.. please post your code so we can help you further.

Comment: All your validation and bulletproofing should be in the registration.php

Comment: IF any error found then save the errors in a session and redirect the user to form_page.Fetch errors from session , display it , and delete the errors from the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your validation and bulletproofing should be in the registration.php

stuff like this:

```
    //both parameters are required, so make sure they were passed-in
if(!isset($_GET['name'])) {
    die('Must pass \'name\');

    //both parameters are required, so make sure they were passed-in
if(!isset($_GET['email'])) {
    die('Must pass \'email\');
}
if(!isset($_GET['passwd'])) {
    die('Must pass \'password\');
} else {
  //do cool stuff here
}
```

Don't forget your JS validation as well for the front end. I really hope this helps and gives you a bit of direction.

Comment: using die() isn't such a good idea.. :( I will use javascript before submitting the form.

Comment: well for testing purposes is what i suppose he's doing on an intranet, he can manually just add everything into the $_GET. I understand what you're saying though. Feel free to edit my answer and add a bit of your theory. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

put your validation codes in "validate.php" or any file name you like 
then change the action to validate.php to

then in validate.php if validation matches the requirements.
header("Location: registration.php");

if not match

header("Location: back to the httml with form.php");

Comment: I see its easier to validate the form using java script. I think I should use javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn form validation here : `http://allitstuff.com/registration-form-in-php-with-validation/`